# Overriding some part of directive's link function

Tags: angularjs

I want to override the some part of link function in UI bootstrap pagination derivative. Found a way in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932414/override-a-directives-link-function) but it will need me too copy the whole code in link function and change specific part, is there any way where I can override it without copying the whole code of original link function

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this with a directive... but with a controller you can make something like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('MachineController', ['$scope', 'dialogs', '$state', '$controller', 'machineService', function ($scope, dialogs, $state, $controller, machineService) {
        angular.extend(this, $controller('BaseController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            dialogs: dialogs,
            dataService: machineService,
            template: '/app/views/dialogs/machineDialog.html'
        }));
    }]);
})();
```

i.e. you could try to extend your directive and just overwrite the link part in the new directive.